# Why is this actionlink not passing my model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have a page where I want to add/remove items to a collection then submit the data with a POST. I am using actionlinks for the adding and removing. I can pass the ID for the item I want to modify and a string of the modification type i.e. remove or add. But my model parameter is always null.

```
@model Models.Claims.ClaimAll



@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Claims.Count; i++)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        int ClaimNum = i + 1;
    <div style="border: solid; border-width: thin; padding: 5px;">
        <div style="background-color: #c3bebe">
            @Html.Label("Claim: " + ClaimNum.ToString())
            <hr />
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Person.PersonID)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimRef)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimRef)


        @{List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>{
        new SelectListItem {Text="Legal", Value = "Legal" },
        new SelectListItem {Text="Immigration", Value = "Immigration"},
        new SelectListItem {Text="Housing", Value = "Housing"}
        };}

        @Html.Label("Claim type:")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimType, new SelectList(list, "Text", "Value", Model.Claims[i].ClaimType))

        <br />

        @{
          for (int ii = 0; ii < Model.Claims[i].ClaimActions.Count; ii++)
          {
              int ActionNum = ii + 1;
            @Html.Label("Claim action: " + ActionNum.ToString())
            <hr />
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].ClaimActionID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].ClaimID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].ClaimStatusID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].ClaimStatus)

            @Html.Label("Claim status:")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClaimActions[i].ClaimStatusID, new SelectList(Model.ClaimStatuses, "ClaimStatusID", "ClaimStatusText", Model.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].ClaimStatusID))

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].Notes)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].Notes)

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].StartDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].StartDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })

            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].EndDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Claims[i].ClaimActions[ii].EndDate, new { @class = "datepicker" }) 
          }

            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @*<input type="submit" value="Add claim action for this claim" name="btnSubmit" />*@
                        @Html.ActionLink("Add claim action for this claim", "AddRemoveClaimActions", new {claimID = Model.Claims[i].ClaimID, text = "Add claim action for this claim",  model = Model  })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*<input type="submit" value="Remove claim action for this claim" name="btnSubmit" />*@
                       @Html.ActionLink("Remove claim action for this claim", "AddRemoveClaimActions", new {claimID = Model.Claims[i].ClaimID, text = "Remove claim action for this claim",  model = Model})
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        }
    </div>
    <br />
    }
}





<hr />
<input type="submit" value="Update claims data" name="btnSubmit" />
<hr />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            currentText: 'Now',
            autoSize: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            showAnim: 'drop',
            highlightWeek: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
        $("#anim").change(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", $(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideGenericLbl() {
        $("#lblGenericMessage").css("color", "red");
        $("#lblGenericMessage").fadeOut(5000);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        hideGenericLbl();

        @if (Model.strMessage != null)
        {
            if (Model.isValidModel == false &&
            Model.strMessage.Contains("Must be at least one claim status if making a claim.") ||
            Model.strMessage.Contains("New claim status available") ||
            Model.strMessage.Contains("One claim status removed."))
            {
                @:$("#modelClaim_ClaimMade").prop('checked', true);
                @:$("#modelPerson_HasDependants").prop('checked', true);
            }
        }

        // Claim made logic
        $("#modelClaim_ClaimMade").click(function () {
            if ($('#modelClaim_ClaimMade').is(':checked')) {

                $("#NewClaim").show();
                //$("#divClaimStatus").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#NewClaim").hide();
                //$("#divClaimStatus").hide();
            }
        });

        if ($('#modelClaim_ClaimMade').is(':checked')) {

            $("#NewClaim").show();
            //$("#divClaimStatus").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#NewClaim").hide();
            //$("#divClaimStatus").hide();
        }

    });
</script>
```

**These are my actionlinks**

```
<table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @*<input type="submit" value="Add claim action for this claim" name="btnSubmit" />*@
                        @Html.ActionLink("Add claim action for this claim", "AddRemoveClaimActions", new {claimID = Model.Claims[i].ClaimID, text = "Add claim action for this claim",  model = Model  })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @*<input type="submit" value="Remove claim action for this claim" name="btnSubmit" />*@
                       @Html.ActionLink("Remove claim action for this claim", "AddRemoveClaimActions", new {claimID = Model.Claims[i].ClaimID, text = "Remove claim action for this claim",  model = Model})
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**Controller method**

```
public ActionResult AddRemoveClaimActions(string claimID, string text, ClaimAll model)
        {
            switch (text)
            {
                case "Add claim action for this claim":
                    #region AddClaimStatus
                    //Add new claim to list
                    model.ClaimActions.Insert(model.ClaimActions.Count, new ClaimAction());
                    // SET to false as Model is not ready for DB
                    model.isValidModel = false;
                    // SET message for the user
                    model.strMessage = "New claim status available";
                    break;
                    #endregion
                case "Remove claim action for this claim":
                    #region RemoveClaimStatus
                    // Can't remove IF only 1 
                    model.isValidModel = false;
                    if (model.ClaimActions.Count == 1)
                    {
                        model.strMessage = "Must be at least one claim status if making a claim.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.ClaimActions.RemoveAt(model.ClaimActions.Count - 1);
                        model.strMessage = "One claim status removed.";

                    }
                    break;
                    #endregion
            }
            return View("~/Views/Claim/EditClaims.cshtml", model);
        }
```

I was originally using buttons to do this but it didn't make sense to do POSTs for modifying the view model. However now I can't access my model in the controller because it's null. I checked that the parameter name is correct and the object type.

Comment: you either pass the model in an ajax post to the action, or do a submit, passing the model the way you do will only call the ToString method and return the full name of the model(unless you override it), but the correct way is mostly ajax

Comment: @MEYWD By Ajax you referring to AJAX.beginform or ajax actionlink?

Comment: `var jqxhr = $.ajax('@Url.Action("AddRemoveClaimActions","ControllerName")', {
        data: {
            claimID: "id",
            text: "text",
            model:
            {
                //model properties....
            }
        }
    } ).done(function() { alert( "success" ); }).fail(function() { alert( "error" ); }).always(function() { alert( "complete" ); });`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/